# Finding some difficulty trying to ORDER BY the SUM(Revenue) with this query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to order the result by using the SUM(Revenue), Below is my code kindly help me fix it, Thank you

SELECT
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Release_date) AS year_released, COUNT(Genre) AS number_of_comedy,SUM(Revenue)AS total_revenue
FROM
Movie_data.movie
WHERE
Genre='Comedy'
GROUP BY
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Release_date)
ORDER BY
SUM(Revenue)
LIMIT
1000

THE ERROR MESSAGE I get is "SELECT list expression references column Release_date which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:19]"

Comment: You can do it using simple `ORDER BY 3` (the position of your column, starting by 1)

Comment: What is the issue with your query?

Comment: The title of the question doesn't seem to have anything to do with ordering... You might want to change it to describe your actual issue.

Comment: I mistakenly stated the error message as my problem title. I wanted to order by the SUM(Revenue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use what you have written.  You can also write:

```
ORDER BY total_revenue
```

Often when ordering by revenue, you want the largest values first:

```
ORDER BY total_revenue DESC
```